# jpype and java.util.Properties

Tags: java, python, properties

I'm attempting to instantiate a Properties object in JPype, and am encountering some difficulty. The commands below...

```
props = JClass('java.util.Properties')
props.setProperty('foo','bar')
```

...return the following:

```
RuntimeError: No matching overloads found. at src/native/common/jp_method.cpp:121
```

I've attempted various forms of the arguments, `str('foo')`, `JString('foo')`, `java.lang.String('foo')`, and nothing seems to work. Setting properties for other classes with this general approach in JPype works just fine (e.g., no problems with `java.lang.System.setProperty('foo','bar')`).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, if you need to read/write .properties files you could try this: http://mgood.github.com/jprops/  Though if you need to create Properties objects to call some Java API, stick with jpype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Properties = JClass('java.util.Properties')
props = Properties()
props.setProperty('foo','bar')
```